# Combine Newton method and Trapezoidal rule

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I got this problem: "Which approximation, $z_2$ do you get when doing one step of Newtons method on $f(x) = 0$ to approximate the unlinear equation $ f(z) = \int_{-1}^1 z^2x^2 dx - 1$. You should use the trapezoidal rule with h = 1 and start with $z_1 = 3$ ".

Okay, I'm assuming that I should do: $ z_2 = z_1 - \frac {\int_{-1}^1 z^2x^2 dx - 1} {f'(z)}$. Is that correct?

If so, my problem is first of all: How do i find the derivative? I only know how to to do it with an integral that has a x as the upper bound.

Moreover, do I replace z within the integral with $z = 3$. I.e: is $z$ within the integral the same as $z_1$?

Comment: This is a bizarre question. The integral can simply be restated as $z^2 \int_{-1}^1 x^2\, dx$ which can be evaluated to a constant. Are we sure this is correctly presented?

Comment: Don't know about bizarre. Why could it be evaluated as a constant?

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 x^2\, dx$ is a definite integral; it evaluates to $\left.\frac{x^3}{3}\right|_{-1}^1 = \frac{1^3 - (-1)^3}{3} = \frac23$.

Comment: Alright, didn't understand what you meant. But I still need to find the derivative. How do I do that when it's not bound by x?

Comment: Do it with respect to $z$, not $x$.